# Should I feed my neural network with "not-approved" profiles, even though I want to predict the approvals?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset

I have a categorical classification problem to solve in which I have a profile of a consumer and a loan order (which has a unique partner) and an end state of that order.

[image]

There are 10% approvals.

I want to have the approval rate for each partner, so I separated only the approvals and trained the network.

Is my approach correct?

What would happen if I feed my network with not approved profiles (maybe with an equal quantity)?

EDIT:

The approval rate for each partner is the percentage rate any user has to be approved by any one partner:

```
'user1': {'partner1': 0.9, 'partner2': 0.08, 'partner3': 0.02, ...}
```

and as classes it will look like this:

```
'user1': {'partner1': 1, 'partner2': 0, 'partner3': 0, ...}
```

To be more specific to try to clarify the problem and question:
If I were going to train a network for binary classification I would include the two classes (the not approved profile and the approved one) for sure.
But as I want the approval rate in comparison with each partner, I don't know if feeding the network with not approved profiles that has all the labels zeroed (even though there is a partner that "generated" that one of the specific zero) would be beneficial or no.

I also thought that I can put the approval binary (approved=1 and not approved=0) into the features and has the labels always with a partner associated (or a 1 into the dummies of labels). And in the prediction (as I want the approval rate) I can always pass the approved label as a "static" feature.

Let me know I you need more clarification please =)

Comment: define this " the approval rate for each partner"

Comment: Without more specific information, I can only say that if you train a neural network for classification, then you should include both classes. Intuitively, if you include only the approvals, then your model doesn't know how to separate/distinguish the classes, since it has no information about the other class.

Comment: It seems like you're asking whether you can train a binary (or maybe $k$-nary) classifier when only one class is used for training data. Is that correct, or are you asking something else? Please edit your question to clarify.